# Subscription model with generics - implement multiple generic interfaces

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns, subscription

So I tried to make a subscription model with generics.. it looked nice, but now I'm running into some issues.

**Receiver**

```
public interface Receiver<E> {
    public void receive(E event);
}
```

**Subscription registry**

```
public class ClientRegistry<T> {
    private Set<Receiver<T>> clients = new HashSet<Receiver<T>>();

    public void subscribe(Receiver<T> client) {
        clients.add(client);
    }

    public void unsubscribe(Receiver<T> client) {
        clients.remove(client);
    }

    public void broadcast(T eventObject) {
        for(Receiver<T> client: clients) {
            client.receive(eventObject);
        }       
    }   
}
```

Sounds good so far, eh?

Now the problems come:

```
public class Screen implements Receiver<KeyEvent>, Receiver<MouseMoveEvent> {
    @Override
    public void receive(KeyEvent event)
    {
        // work
    }

    @Override
    public void receive(MouseMoveEvent event)
    {
        // work
    }
}
```

Now this is invalid syntax:

```
The interface Receiver cannot be implemented more than once
with different arguments: Receiver<MouseMoveEvent> and Receiver<KeyEvent>
```

**How can I alter my system to keep it as generic as possible, but make it work?**

Comment: As far as I know, even without generics, you cannot implement an interface twice.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I thought with generics I will be able to. Anyway, how to do it in a better way?

Comment: why can't you program directly to the interface? (implements Receiver<Event>)?

Comment: But event is not an interface.

Comment: it actually doesn't matter as long as it is a base class of KeyEvent and MouseMoveEvent

Comment: Now I've added the receive methods to the question, so it's cleaner. Do you think this will work if both extend Event?

Comment: Actually it won't work, - you won't be able to subscribe such class to a registry.

Comment: @m9 It still won't work.

Comment: you'd have to use only the event api to write your receive method and take an Event parameter, so that you can declaire implements Receiver<Event>

Comment: Yes, but then what? Some `instanceof` jungle to differentiate the events?

Comment: no, you'd use the different subclasses of events and virtual methods to achieve different behavior when needed. You should look up a book on OOP

Comment: Event holds some data, so I need getters for that. How would your solution deal with that?

Comment: well the Event class should model that. As I said you should maybe grab some tutorial on OOP to clear things up before coming up with a messed up design. Those issues are basic OOP stuff.

Comment: I don't think "read a tutorial" kind of answer is what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reverse the order, and use a [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern):

```
import java.util.*;

interface Event{
    void receive(Receiver receiver);    
}

class KeyEvent implements Event{
    @Override
    public void receive(Receiver receiver){
        receiver.receive(this);
    }   
}

class MouseEvent implements Event {
    @Override
    public void receive(Receiver receiver){
        receiver.receive(this);
    }   
}

interface Receiver {
    void receive(KeyEvent event);
    void receive(MouseEvent event);
}

class ClientRegistry {
    private Set<Receiver> clients = new HashSet<Receiver>();

    public void subscribe(Receiver client) {
        clients.add(client);
    }

    public void unsubscribe(Receiver client) {
        clients.remove(client);
    }

    public void broadcast(Event eventObject) {
        for(Receiver client: clients) {
            eventObject.receive(client);
        }       
    }   
}

public class Screen implements Receiver {

    public void receive(KeyEvent event) {
        //work
        System.out.println("Processing key event");
    }
    public void receive(MouseEvent event) {
        //work
        System.out.println("Processing mouse event");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        ClientRegistry registry = new ClientRegistry();
        registry.subscribe(new Screen());
        registry.broadcast(new MouseEvent());
    }
}
```

There is not way to generify the Receiver interface, but it is indeed type safe and as you can see, I reverse the order, since now it is the event the one which chooses the receiver and not otherwise.

Comment: Actually, I'm now using a similar pattern, so I'll give you the point.

Answer (score 2):

Don't make the Screen class itself implement the two Receiver interfaces. Instead, use composition:

```
public class Screen {
    private Receiver<KeyEvent> keyReceiver = new Receiver<KeyEvent>() {
        ...
    };

    private Receiver<MouseEvent> mouseReceiver = new Receiver<MouseEvent>() {
        ...
    };
}
```